# How can i create left to right and then inverse animation in android?

Tags: android, translate-animation

How can I create one animation which always translates from left to right and then if animation stops it turns the other way and translates from right to left. I can create Translate animation in xml and programatically too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create this `xml`, it will translate from left to right and from right to left.

`/res/anim/translate.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="10%p"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:startOffset="0" />

    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="10%p"
        android:toXDelta="-10%p"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:startOffset="2000" />

</set>
```

Suppose you want to apply this animation to an image then write the code below in your class file.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate);
image.startAnimation(animation);
```

**Edit:**

If you want your animation to repeat infinitely add the following attributes to the `translate` tag.

```
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
```

Comment: please be aware that this solution uses an old Animation framework

Comment: And how Can I make it infinite animation? I have read that repeat count property in animation list did not work well.

Comment: @Csabi you can do it by using repeatCount and repeatCode attributes, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your min API level actually. Essentially You should look at [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) class.

Let's say you have `view` to animate, and `parent` - parent of this view. Your code would look like this:

```
final float startX = 0; //start position
final float endX = parent.getWidth() - view.getWidth(); //end position - right edge of the parent
```

**API 12+**:

```
view.animate().translationX(endX).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            view.animate().translationX(startX).start();
        }
    }).start();
```

**API 16+**:

```
view.animate().translationX(endX).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.animate().translationX(startX).start();
        }
    }).start();
```

Your `startX` and `endX` might be different - depending on your needs.

Please note that `start()` method call is optional.

Also I have not mentioned solution for API <12 since I personally think that nobody should support those legacy APIs :)

Comment: Dakujem Pavel. Your answer was correct, and hellpfull